# Google maps wont load in IE8

Tags: html, google-maps, iframe

As every developer im stumbled on an hard part. An website which isn't made by me but i need to fix the problems. And to be honest at this point im stuck at one problem.

If you please would go to:
http://ikeet.net/bijdeboer/index.php?page=profielen&id=30

And press the **tab** "Contact".

In any browser except IE8 (tested IE7, IE9, firefox, chrome, safari) the google maps is correct. But when i render the map in IE8 the only thing i see is one big white block where the map should have been.

So to be honest i googled some solutions but i don't have a clue how to solve this.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the trailing comma here:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latingmarker, 
          map: map,      })
```

So it would be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latingmarker, 
          map: map 
     })
```

Comment: Please see my comment at adam.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a JavaScript error.

Remove the comma after map in this code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latingmarker, 
          map: map,
     })
```

Comment: It doesnt use the javascript, (removed it now) its pure an iframe solution.

Comment: does it work when the map does not start hidden - try it in the default tab. I have had problems hding and showing maps before